# How to get a floating point infinity that when multiplied by zero gives zero

Tags: python, floating-point, infinity

How do I get a "small enough" infinity that its product with zero is zero?

I'm using an integer programming solver for Python, and some of my variables have infinite cost. I can't use `float('inf')` because `float('inf')*0 = NaN`

Comment: "Infinite cost" sounds like you want to constrain them to be equal to zero...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use the largest finite number that `float` can hold:

```
In [9]: print sys.float_info.max
1.79769313486e+308

In [10]: sys.float_info.max * 0
Out[10]: 0.0
```

Comment: That's a clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking for a "smaller infinity", which doesn't exist, it may be easier to trap the `NaN` and substitute zero for it. To do this, you can use the fact that `NaN` is not equal to any float value, even itself. This approach is convenient because generally you can use it at the end of a chain of calculations (since the `NaN` will cascade through and make the results all `NaN`).

```
possible_inf = float("+inf")
result = possible_inf * 0
result = result if result == result else 0
```

You could also just trap for the infinity itself earlier on:

```
possible_inf = float("+inf")
result = 0 if abs(possible_inf) == float("+inf") else possible_inf * 0
```

Comment: IEEE 754 representation of infinity is simply a bit pattern, not the representation of a number. Arithmetic operations will always give NaN.

Answer (score 2):

NAN isn't zero. u can use numpy to check the NAN value and convert it to zero.

```
from numpy import isnan
result = 0 if isnan(result) else result
```